# Doctrine ORM: Create Table Like Another

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine

Is there any way, when using Doctrine, to create a table like another? I know in MySQL there is a function to do so:

```
CREATE TABLE user2 LIKE user;
```

and tables user and user2 will be identical. Can this be done in Doctrine?

Comment: I did not even know this is possible in MySQL. Thanks for your question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that what you are looking for is to define (let's use your example) *on the schema level* that `user2` inherits from `user` when your model is generated. You can do this by using doctrine's *concrete* inheritance which [is described in the documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/inheritance#concrete).

So, in your `schema.yml`:

```
User:
  columns:
    name: string

User2:
  inheritance:
    extends: User
    type: concrete
  columns:
    something: int
```

This way `user2` will be a separate table and contain the same columns ("name") as previously defined in `user`. I'm not sure why you would like two **identical** tables, but that is most definitely possible using the above method.

Comment: This is probably the best solution for this problem... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think no. :(

You can create tables from template like here http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/cookbook/1_1/en/plug-and-play-schema-information-with-templates or use Doctrine_RawSql.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine provides a simple method for this: Doctrine_Record::copy().

```
  $copy = $user->copy();
```

Notice that copying the record with copy() returns a new record (state TDIRTY) with the
values of the old record, and it copies the relations of that record. If you do not want to copy
the relations too, you need to use copy(false).

*Get a copy of user without the relations*

**$copy = $user->copy(false)**;